# Why such specific requirements regarding eglah arufah?

Tags: halacha, eglah-arufah

Why is it that Eglah arufah only applies when the dead man is not floating in a river or hanging on a noose? And not only that, but he had to have been killed by a sharp metal object. Why is that?

Comment: The talmud explains that this is a *chok*. Thus, even if reasons may be given, the reasons are not necesssary. The details of a chok are set by the initial declaration and maintained as *halachah leMoshe miSinai*.

Comment: It seems that the Torah's opinion is that where the dead man is found on land, this introduces a certain rottenness into the land, which needs expiation. The idea of defiling the land is common throughout Tenach.

Comment: I like grapkes reason.